# What Image Resizing System is Google Using in App Engine Blob Store

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, image-scaling

In Google's App Engine there is a very fast image resizing system. I'm interested in implementing something similar and cannot use GAE because the images are sensitive data (School trip photos with children etc) and so they cannot be sent outside our walled garden (data protection stuff).

Does anyone know how the app engine manages to resize images so fast? A solution using any language or technology that can achieve similar performance would be of interest!

Comment: are the regular image libraries (for example PHP's GD) not fast enough? how fast do you need it? have you run tests with your chosen platform and how far was it from your speed goal?

Comment: in short.. years of experience with looooots of data...

Comment: I'm interested specifically in the technology Google is using to achieve their high performance resizing. I've seen and used many of the existing libraries (ImageMagick, GD etc) and none of them are as fast as GAE's solution, no matter how fast the CPU and how much memory I throw at a server.

Comment: I'm wondering if a GPU-based solution is in use. Knowing what stack they are using would be very interesting and help to build a similar solution in-house.